# transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

**TransitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation? (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController:** 
how to solve it, no exception is printing but above error show on calling

```
-(IBAction)presume:(id)sender
{
        [self returnToRootViewController];

}



 - (UIViewController*)topmostViewController
    {
        UIViewController* vc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
        while(vc.presentedViewController) {
            vc = vc.presentedViewController;
        }
        return vc;
    }

    - (void)returnToRootViewController
    {
        UIViewController* vc = [self topmostViewController];
        while (vc) {
            if(vc.presentingViewController) {
                if ([vc isKindOfClass:[CarDetailVC class]])
                {

                    @try {



                        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];

                    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

                        NSLog(@"exception=%@",exception);
                    } @finally {

                    }


                 }

            }
            vc = vc.presentingViewController;
        }



    }
```

Comment: I see the relationship here to your earlier question.  Do you just want to dismiss until the CarDetailVC is on top?  That can be done more straight-forwardly

Comment: yes i tried above solution and stuck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a more direct path to the target vc (the instance of CarDetailVC).

```
- (UIViewController*)vcWithClass:(Class)klass {
    UIViewController* vc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    while(![vc.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:klass]) {
        vc = vc.presentedViewController;
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Now, get to it and dismiss the vc it presented.

```
- (void)returnToCarVC {
    CarDetailVC *carVC =(CarDetailVC*) [self vcWithClass:[CarDetailVC self]];
    UIViewController *presented = carVC.presentedViewController;
    [presented dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: Warning in Incompatible pointer types initialising CarDetailVC * with an expression of type UIViewcontroller 
    CarDetailVC *carVC = [self vcWithClass:[CarDetailVC self]];

Comment: In not near a dev machine anymore , but that's minor: just cast the result*carVC = (CarDetailVC)...